# PHP script to send and retrive sms from a website

Tags: sms-gateway, home-automation

I'm not sure where to begin, but got a case I need help from others where and if possible to solve.
Thing is, got a new alarm system at home, this system uses sms function so I can send a short code to my alarm asking for status if it`s ON or OFF, or i can turn it on/off from an sms.

Since both the sms number and code is strictly personal, I would not like to tell my carpenter the codes, but in the mean while he is working at my home, I can give him a login to my site, where he can see if the alarm is turned on or even turn it on/off by him self.

I would like to build me a website, that does the same. 
Got a login to my site, when logged in, i would like the website to send an sms automatically, then retrieve the answer and display it on the website.

Is this even possible ? If so, anyone can past me in the right direction here ?

Thanks in advance =)

Comment: What a silly idea... Just give home the code and change it when he's done.

Answer (score 0):

You can send an SMS from a website. Most mobile operators will gladly offer you an apropriate API.

For instance Deutsche Telekom has an API called "Developer Garden" that allows you to send SMS via a WebService and much more.

see here for an example: [www.developergarden.com](https://www.developergarden.com/)

Other providers may also offer such services.

Answer (score 0):

you need an sms gateway ( we use these guys : http://inteltech.com.au/, but nearly any will do )

Your easiest option is to find one where you can insert SMS'es for sending via a URL, eg in our case the URL looks like this:
http://inteltech.com.au/secure-api/send.single.php?username=[user]&key=[longcode]&method=http&senderid=[id]&sms=[phonenumber]&message=[here's the message]

it's extremely simple to use. If your site handles the login otherwise, then you can use this for the rest.

Now, how to receive SMS'es is a bit tricker :)

But this provider, for example, offers you options to;

- Send the reply as an email to a nominated email address.
- Send the reply as an email to the original user who sent the message.
- Send the reply as an SMS to a nominated mobile number.
- POST the reply to your website or application . e.g. We can call a http/https request to your script

as you can see, both the email and the POST options are providing great ways to integrate.
I'd say if you don't handle incoming email already, then stick to the POST method.

voila :)